# Maven profiles - dev vs production

Tags: maven, maven-2

I was curious about how to set up development vs production maven profiles. Should I only put the snapshots repo in the dev profile, and the other artifacts (local repo, for releases etc), in the production profile?

What are the major things which different profiles of these types?

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is, obviously, settings among Prod, Test, and Dev profiles. Things like

- Database connectivity
- Properties like resource settings, thread-pool configuration, log file location and it's size
- Storage settings like for local you might have a `/mnt/media` but for Prod, you may want S3

varies in these profiles.

Now come to release, usually Test profile/s has SNAPSHOT releases (like nightly builds) that is configured to go to SNAPSHOT repository of yours. And a Prod profile is released, usually, using Maven Release Plugin, that automatically knocks the SNAPSHOT off your release version/artifacts. And is configured to store the artifact in RELEASES repo. The configuration for these repos goes like

```
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <distributionManagement>
            <snapshotRepository>
                <id>snapshotrepo</id>
                <name>Repository for snapshots only</name>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
                <url>http://repo.company.com/snapshots</url>
            </snapshotRepository>
        </distributionManagement>
        .....
        .....
        .....

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        </distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                <id>releaserepo</id>
                <name>Final release artifacts</name>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
                <url>http://repo.company.com/releases</url>
            </repository>
        </distributionManagement>
        ....
        ....
```

The credential to these repos goes into [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Dev profile is usually not configured to release to company repo (as it will be too cluttered of useless artifacts), it just gets installed in your local repo, as SNAPSHOT and overwritten on each build.

Comment: Why would you like to define a release and dev profile for different repositories...That's the reason why you have release and SNAPSHOT's which is already the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Usually (in my experience) the different repos are configured in settings.xml, and not in separate profiles (except maybe in profiles enabled by default).

**Example of a default profile:**

```
<profile>
<id>default</id>
<activation>
<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://some_url/content/groups/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://some_url/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

If you are concerned about having SNAPSHOT dependencies in your releases, you can use tools like [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) to verify that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies in your project.

> What are the major things which different profiles of these types?

You often use profiles to separate between different build environments. For instance, using a CI you often put plugins for static code analysis, reporting, test coverage etc. in a profile that is only activated when building on the CI server (since it takes more time to run it with these tools enabled).

Another use is to separate out specific part of the application, for instance you don't want the acceptance-test submodule to run on every mvn test, but only sometimes when you enable the **mvn test -p acceptanceTests** profile

**The problem with environment specific builds**

Now, profiles are sometimes used to separate configurations like connections strings, enpoints etc. In my view that is not ideal, since you end up with environment specific builds. Sometimes that is hard to avoid, but most of the time this can be solved by externalizing configuration (make sure to have proper configuration management), and use the same binary artifact in dev/test/prod. That way you are sure that the build that passed system test is the same as that in prod etc.

Comment: Why contain both the snapshot repo AND the artifact repo in the default profile? Even though on the default profile you are only deploying to the snapshot repo, is the other still there, just so you can ACCESS the main artifact repo? On a "release" profile would it make most sense to include maven-release-plugin directly in settings.xml, and leave OUT the snapshot repo?

Comment: Having both the release and snapshot repository in the default profile is convenient. That way you can refer to the repository by id in <distributionManagement /> and by invoking mvn deploy it is deployed to the snapshot repository if it's a X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT version, or the release repository if it's an actual release X.Y.Z.

Comment: Most of the projects I've seen doesn't have a separate release profile, so the release-plugin is nested in the default <plugins/> entity in the pom. If project policies calls for it I guess it makes sense to put the release-plugin and related plugins (maven-gpg-plugin for example) in a separate profile. Putting the release-plugin in settings is also an option, but that would probably be in the <pluginManagement/> I think, and you would have to put it in the project pom to enable it.

Comment: Have a look in this pom for an example of a release profile: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I'm specifically confused about how to do this for PRIVATE repos. How do I make my internal repo private by default? If I have an INTERNAL (builds, proxy to maven central), and a SNAPSHOT repository, do I need to put my credentials in twice, one per repo, in the <server> area?

Comment: What is the difference between merely adding each repository, and adding a proxy?

Comment: If I merely add my repos as shown above, with credentials to snapshot and internal repos respectively, AND my internal repo is configured in archiva to proxy to maven central, will it still use my own archiva instance for ALL dependencies, even without proxy settings in setting.xml?